# Apply style to the classes and not effect the others in navagation LI?

Tags: html, css, styles

When adding style to bmenu more importantly the margin/padding, font size,font weight to btmenu it apply them too all the ones under it like submenu li . How can I separate the styles to not apply them to submenues?
I dont want the text to look like its 50 pixels down, dont want the font weight or centered yet.. how can I only apply style to the classes and not effect the others?????.
Whatever style I apply to: 
btmenu li a 
it will apply to 
         submenu li a 
and I dont want that I want each style separate.

```css
#btmenu{
z-index:1;
position:relative;
width:100%;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:62px;
text-align:center;/* this is applied to submenu*/
}
#btmenu > a{
font-weight:bold;/* this is applied to submenu*/
font-size:15px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
line-height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
text-align:center;/* this is applied to submenu*/
}
ul#btmenu > li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
display: inline;
}
#btmenu li > a{
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#btmenu > li > a:hover{
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 
}
/*     SUB MENU     */
.sub_menu{
display:none;
}
#btmenu > li:hover > .sub_menu{
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;/*no need for height or width*/
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:#666;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table;
padding-right:3px;
border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.sub_menu > li{
margin:0px;
border: 1px solid blue;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
height:125px;
width:47%;
}
.sub_menu  > li a{
display:block;
vertical-align: middle;
height:200px;
width:200px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
margin:0;/* not applied??*/
padding:0;/* not applied???*/
}
.ee{margin:0;
padding:0;}
```

```html
<ul id="btmenu">



<li class="top_quote">
  <a href="services">services</a>
<ul class="sub_menu">
<li class=""><a href="services"><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="services"><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="services"><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="services"><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="services"><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>



</li>



<li class="top_quote">
<a href="locations">locations</a>
 

<ul class="sub_menu">
<li class="ee"><a href="tel:16142585555">test1</a></li>
<li class="ee"><a href="tel:16148411111 ">test2</a></li>
<li class="ee"><a href="tel:16148859957">test3</a></li>
<li class="ee"><a href="tel:16148689999">test4</a></li>
<li class="ee"><a href="tel:16144212222">test5</a></li>
<li class="ee"><a href="tel:16144978888">test6</a></li>
<li class="ee"><a href="tel:16142585555">test7</a></li>
<li class="ee"><a href="tel:16148690006">test8</a></li>
</ul>

</li>


<li class="top_quote"><a href="partners">partners</a>
 

<ul class="sub_menu">
<li class=""><a href=""><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href=""><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href=""><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href=""><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href=""><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href=""><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href=""><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>
<li class=""><a href=""><img src="" width="189" height="189" alt=""></a></li>

</ul>




</li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="ourwork">our work</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="contact">contact</a></li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moved the style from .btmenu to

```
#btmenu > a {
font-weight:bold;/* this is applied to submenu*/
font-size:15px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
line-height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not exactly clear but if your question is how you can apply styles to a specific `li` elements and not other `li` elements, here's how you can do it:

```css
ul > li {
  color: blue;
}

ul > li.specific {
  color: red;
}

ul > li.specific:hover {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="specific">Specific li</li>
  <li>Another li</li>
  <li>Another li</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following rules

```
#btmenu{
  font-weight:bold;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  font-size:15px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  line-height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
}
```

should be applied directly to the element you really want them on. `#btmenu` doesn't have any text; its descendants do. You are currently relying on style inheritance to get the top level menus to style, but the result is lower level menus also get the style.

So this might be a better selector (which you already use later on):

```
#btmenu > li > a {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:15px;
  height:62px;
  line-height:62px;
}
```

As for `text-align: center`, I assume you really want that on the `<ul>` so you will have to break the inheritance chain later on with something like:

```
#btmenu {
  text-align: center;
}
#btmenu > ul {
   text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: this still applies those styles to the submenu li a

Comment: if you remove those completely thats how the submenu should look then add styles to btmenu li a and it will auto apply them to submenu li a

Comment: @qwertyyuiop I'm not sure what you are saying exactly, but the `>` operator should prevent it from being applied to the submenus.

Comment: it does not is the problem ill have an example up sometime today.

Comment: it inherited those styles from ul#btmenu hense why the text is  font-weight:bold;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  font-size:15px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  line-height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/ how can i stop this????

Comment: fixed it tks for the help #btmenu > a {
 font-weight:bold;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  font-size:15px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
  line-height:62px;/* this is applied to submenu*/
}